# Python script scheduled through Cron job is failing

Tags: python, cron

Context - I have a Python script that reads Music folder and opens VLC player for each music file one at a time(1 song will play, VLC will close and then another will play so on and so forth). When I execute the python script from IDE or Terminal the script runs successfully. However when I execute it through Cron job it fails.

Python Script - Please note, I have disabled looping for Testing purpose.

```
import os,subprocess
my_path = '/home/tushar/Music/Devotional/'
songs_list = os.listdir(my_path)
song_str = ''
#for song in songs_list:
   #subprocess.run(["vlc", my_path+song])
subprocess.run(["vlc", "/home/tushar/PycharmProjects/Morning Devotional Songs/Ganesha.opus"])
```

Crontab -e

```
47 10 * * * python3 /home/tushar/PycharmProjects/Morning\ Devotional\ Songs/main.py >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

Cron job log -

```
> [000055ed64567cf8] core interface error: no suitable interface module
> [000055ed6445a148] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none"
> initialization failed [000055ed64567cf8] dbus interface error: Failed
> to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a
> dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11 [000055ed64567cf8] core
> interface error: no suitable interface module [000055ed6445a148] core
> libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
> [000055ed6445a148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default
> interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface. [000055ed64567cf8]
> qt4 interface error: Could not connect to X server [000055ed64567cf8]
> skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory [000055ed64567cf8]
> [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console". VLC media player
> 2.2.4 Weatherwax Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
> 
> Shutting down. [000055ed64567cf8] [cli] lua interface: Requested
> shutdown. [000055ed64567cf8] [cli] lua interface error: Error loading
> script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/intf/cli.luac: lua/intf/modules/host.lua:279:
> Interrupted. [00007f977c0178c8] core stream error: cannot pre fill
> buffer
```

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: That is because jobs executed via cron do not have DISPLAY environment variable set (in other words non-GUI mode by default), and can not talk to display server. Either set the display variable (hackish) or as the error says use `cvlc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cron job log provides a clue as to why your job fails.

> Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface. [000055ed64567cf8] qt4 interface error: Could not connect to X server

What this means is y X server is not found and you have to run the same task without the interface like:

```
subprocess.run(["cvlc", "/home/tushar/PycharmProjects/Morning Devotional Songs/Ganesha.opus"])
```

`cvlc` is like vlc without the interface and on the command line. Try it and let us know!